# Custom route of resources to a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create a route for users' schedule but with an action in a different controller.

With the following route, I have an infinite loop of requests for the user.

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      get "schedule" => "schedule#user"
    end
  end
```

The logs from development.log :

```
...

  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 122 LIMIT 1
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 122 LIMIT 1
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 122 LIMIT 1
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 122 LIMIT 1

...
```

I tried to remove the `member` block but it's still blocked in the loop.

It seems to be in an infinite recursion but I don't know why.

**EDIT 1:**

I have the same issue with `get "users/:user_id/schedule" => "schedule#user"`

**EDIT 2:**

My action is very simple :

```
  def user
    @courses = Course.includes(:speakers).where("users.id = ?", params[:user_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'user' }
    end
  end
```

Speakers are `User`s and it's a many-to-many relationship with courses.
And my view is just a calendar in JS with a `each` loop through `@courses`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what is the url that you need to get. What action in which controller is.

I would go with:

**edit**

```
get 'users/:id/schedule' => 'schedule#user', as: :schedule
```

and this will be outside of any resources blocks. If this is not exactly what you are looking for post your controller and action that you want to call and I'll update my answer.. I'll try at least. Good luck.

**controller**

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
  def schedule
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
get "users/:id/schedule" => 'sales#schedule', as: :schedule
```

**link**

```
<%= link_to "go", schedule_path(user.id) %>
```

**result**

```
<a href="/users/1/schedule">Schedule</a>
```

clicking on it requires the template, that I don't have it. I won't go that far :)

Comment: I want this url : `users/:id/schedule` and I have a `ScheduleController` for this specific page. `ScheduleController` displays a schedule for other models too.

Comment: I've updated the answer, should work, think we can use teamviewer to solve this issue and then post the solution? it's hard to debug without seeing the logs and code

Comment: or, can you describe what this action will do? like: clicking on user should render that or redirect there etc..

Comment: I updated my question. I am going to try to reproduce the issue in a new project.

Comment: I did it in my app and it worked, just replicate your case.. I'll update the answer right away.